# Can't start Ferdi in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: gpu, 22.04

`[182245:0505/170029.269490:FATAL:gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc(415)] GPU process isn't usable. Goodbye. Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)`

This happened after installing ubuntu 22.04, was working fine.

- ferdi was NOT a snap app

Comment: https://getferdi.com/faq/i-cannot-start-ferdi-anymore-what-should-i-do/

Answer (score 0):

To install Ferdi messaging app in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install ferdi
```

To start Ferdi from the terminal type either `ferdi` or `snap run ferdi` You can also start Ferdi by clicking its icon in the Dash.